# Why I am seeing my headers like this "labels.frontend.auth.login_box_title" on my local host

Tags: laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hPNv.jpg)

what to do I need to do with this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so before asking your next question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [localization keys](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/localization). These keys reference a string in a language file (which live in `resources/lang/{lang}/{file.php}`, where `{lang}` is an [ISO 639 Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes), e.g: `en`).  For example, `labels.frontend.auth.login_box_title` refers to the `resources/lang/{lang}/labels.php` file.

You will see the localization key output when there is no matching value found because it is used as the fallback. For example if you reference `labels.name` and the file `labels.php` doesn't exist, or `name` does not exist in `labels.php`, then the key (`labels.name`) will be output instead.

You appear to be using [Laravel 5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate) which ships with a [variety of languages](https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate/tree/master/resources/lang). I suspect that the problem is you have configured your application to use a language that is not supported, or you are missing your `resources/lang/*` files.

1. Verify that the files exist in `resources/lang`
2. Verify that your `locale` is set to one of the included languages in `.env`, e.g: `en`

If you continue to have issues, please update your question to include:

1. A screenshot of your `resources/lang/` folder
2. A copy of the `APP_*` values from your `.env`

Comment: You are too awesome. Thanks